# What Is a Dragon Heartstring?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures, wandlore

Dragon Heartstring is used for wand cores by both Ollivander and Gregorovitch. What part of a dragon's heart do the Heartstrings come from? Do Heartstrings come from an entirely different part of the dragon, despite the name?

**What is a Dragon Heartstring? What part of the dragon does a Heartstring come from?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No JKR info that I could find, but most likely it is **Chordae Tendineae**

> The chordae tendineae are tendons linking the papillary muscles to the tricuspid valve in the right ventricle and the mitral valve in the left ventricle. As the papillary muscles contract and relax, the chordae tendineae transmit the resulting increase and decrease in tension to the respective valves, causing them to open and close. **The chordae tendineae are string-like in appearance and are sometimes referred to as "heart strings."** (*<strike>[source](http://www.cardioconsult.com/Anatomy/)</strike>* *[source](https://web.archive.org/web/20080101061705/http://www.cardioconsult.com/Anatomy/)*)

Since dragon heart generally plays role in [assorted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fafnir) lore, it makes sense that a wand core associated with an actual part of dragon's heart would be considered powerful.

Comment: Does that mean that they had to kill a dragon for every few wands?

Comment: @chama Either that or they asked it *very* politely.

Comment: @charma: Maybe they got it from a dragon that has more than one heart, and if you remove one heart, the dragon survives, and maybe even regenerates a new heart.  Or maybe they used dragons that have died of natural causes.  In any case, this might explain what Charlie Weasley's actual job is.

Comment: They weren't artificially manufacturing those unicorn horns for potions either. :P I would presume that they farmed dragons specifically for wand cores/potion ingredients, much like we farm cows for food and leather.

Comment: I think my head just exploded trying to picture a "dragon farm."

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27872/can-any-body-part-be-regenerated-with-magic about whether you can regenerate a dragon's heart.

Comment: Off-topic: farming dragons for heartstrings reminds me to Order of the Stick webcomic strip 744 http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0744.html . Elan: “Wait, don't phoenixes explode when they die?”  Tarquin: “Right, which is why it's so pricey. The liver has to be cut out while the bird is still alive.”

Comment: @J.T.Grimes Better than being burned to a crisp by working on an actual dragon farm.

Comment: The heart related link is dead. Anyway that sounds like it's describing a mammalian heart. If a dragon is a reptile (or at least it's probably not a mammal even in the wizard world), it would have a 3 chambered heart and a single ventricle, so would this structure even exist in a dragon?