# Could George's ear have been healed by Snape?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape, dark-arts

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* George's ear gets cut off by a stray *Sectumsempra* (cast by Snape).

Now this was an act of Dark Magic and therefore George's ears could not be healed:

> Mrs. Weasley looked around and said, “I can’t make it grow back,
>   not when it’s been removed by Dark Magic. But it could have been
>   so much worse. . . . He’s alive.”
>
> *- Molly Weasley - Fallen Warrior (Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows).*

But in *Half-Blood Prince* Snape clearly heals Draco Malfoy's wounds (inflicted by Harry's *Sectumsempra*), using some incantation and tracing his wand over the wounds:

> The door banged open behind Harry and he looked up, terrified:
>   Snape had burst into the room, his face livid. Pushing Harry
>   roughly aside, he knelt over Malfoy, drew his wand, and traced it
>   over the deep wounds Harry’s curse had made, muttering an incantation
>   that sounded almost like song. The flow of blood seemed
>   to ease; Snape wiped the residue from Malfoy’s face and repeated
>   his spell. Now the wounds seemed to be knitting.
>
> *- Sectumsempra (Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince).*

***If* Snape was available, could he have healed George's ear?**

Whilst writing this question, I have realised that George's ear was **cut off**, and not just injured. This may make a difference; perhaps George's ear couldn't have been **re-grown** due to being severed using Dark Magic.

Comment: What I don't understand is why they didn't just go to a muggle doctor and have it sewn back on.  Both Harry and Hermoine knew about what muggle doctors were capable of.  Why did neither of them suggest that as an option?

Comment: @Robert Did they still have the ear?

Comment: @GoodPerson I don't think it's ever mentioned if they do or don't.

Comment: [Meta discussion concerning this question.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11028/what-should-be-done-when-a-non-answer-has-been-accepted)

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that it fell to earth, horrifying some poor Muggle gardener.

Comment: @MissMonicaE Along with a certain owl, a Firebolt and various other things too, I'm sure. I somehow doubt they had the ear still in any case. After all there was hole enough for a joke about being 'holey' (was that the spelling ?).

Comment: @Robert If they had it don't you think they would have mentioned it? The fact they didn't mention it would suggest they don't. Of course they do say they couldn't find Mad-Eye's eye but even so it's very unlikely that it wouldn't have fallen to the ground and as MissMonicaE says it probably scared a gardener - unless maybe it was eaten by a rodent or a dog or something like that. Hell it could have fallen down into a chimney or on the roof of a car or ...

Answer (score 19):

I don't think you wanna read too much into Snape's treatment of Malfoy's wounds.

First of all, Harry has never used the spell before and used it in a state of panic. He 'wav[ed] his wand wildly' and did not get a clean hit.

> [W]ater poured everywhere and Harry slipped over as Malfoy, his face contorted, cried, 'Cruci-'
>
> 'SECTUMSEMPRA!' bellowed Harry from the floor, waving his wand wildly.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.489 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 24, *Sectumsempra*

What's more, he seems to have cast the spell with minimal malice and intent:

> 'You know I wouldn't've used a spell like that, not even on Malfoy, [...]'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.495 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 24, *Sectumsempra*

So these are flesh wounds, really, cuts. Cuts caused by Dark Magic, yes, but as you raise in the question, nothing has been cut off.

Even so, there is still some risk of scarring, even though a powerful wizard and the creator of the curse, attended the scene immediately. Although circumstantial evidence suggests Malfoy escaped scarring:

> 'You need the hospital wing. There may be a certain amount of scarring, but if you take dittany immediately we might avoid even that ... come ...'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.489 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 24, *Sectumsempra*

So my first point is obviously that this was an inexperienced casting of an advanced spell, and it wasn't a clean hit.

But I think more important is the point you raise in the question and that I have already touched on.

Molly (and, through her, the author) is quite explicit in *Deathly Hallows*:

> 'I think so, although there's no chance of replacing his ear, not when it's been cursed off -'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.64 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 5, *Fallen Warrior*

Body parts removed by Dark Magic cannot be put back on.

Whereas in the case of cuts, scratches, lacerations and so on things are a little different. Look at Bill. He was savaged by Fenrir Greyback, but nothing was bitten off. He was scarred, but even there his wounds were closed.

> 'No, I don't think that Bill will be a true werewolf,' said Lupin, 'but that does not mean that there won't be some contamination. Those are cursed wounds. They are unlikely ever to heal fully, and - and Bill might have some wolfish characteristics from now on.'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.572 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 29, *The Phoenix Lament*

He can't be healed fully, but it was possible to improve upon

> an unrecognisable face lying on Bill's pillow, so badly slashed and ripped that he looked grotesque.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.572 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 29, *The Phoenix Lament*

To the point where, bathing in Fleur's radiance at the wedding,

> Bill did not look as though he had ever met Fenrir Greyback.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.121 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 8, *The Wedding*

Although this is only 'once Fleur had reached him' and he is described as "badly scarred" before the battle of the seven Potters.

Having said that, it is noticeable that the wounds caused by Harry's Sectumsempra are much more easily healed, so we might posit that Sectumsempra is much weaker than the curse imparted by Greyback and if it was possible to heal Malfoy's wounds it was possible to heal George's.

> Madam Pomfrey was dabbing at his wounds with some harsh-smelling green ointment. Harry remembered how Snape had mended Malfoy's *Sectumsempra* wounds so easily with his wand.
>
> 'Can't you fix them with a charm or something?' he asked the matron.
>
> 'No charm will work on these,' said Madam Pomfrey. 'I've tried everything I know, but there is no cure for werewolf bites.'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.572 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 29, *The Phoenix Lament*

But I would argue that even in Malfoy's case, he was at risk of scarring from Harry's inept slashing. So I don't personally think Snape's ability to heal Malfoy's cuts implies that ears, once cursed off, could be reattached, not given Molly Weasley's direct statement and the state of Mad-Eye Moody after years as an Auror.

Or to state my point more plainly. I would argue that, if Bill's wounds can be treated to the point where he is scarred, but the wounds are healed, which is to say they are closed and he is no longer bleeding, then it should come as little surprise that Malfoy's injuries caused by Harry's clumsy use of a spell he did not understand could be almost completely cured leaving little or no trace. But that does not imply that if the same curse is used by an experienced caster to remove a body part, that that body part can be reattached by magic. You provide in your question a flat statement to the contrary, and my intention with the answer is to show why I don't think there are sufficient grounds to object to it.

Comment: Snape thought of the scene with George when he prepared his _Prince’s tale_, essentially apologizing (in the sense of “I didn’t mean to hit him”). If he knew of a cure, he could have included a memory demonstrating how to re-grow a body part after Sectumsempra; but he didn’t, so probably there really was no way to do it.

Comment: The fact Harry waved his wand is what made the wound more serious. Remember that it acts like an invisible sword slashing.

Comment: @chirlu Would he? Severus probably expected the ear to be gone. Or useless at that point. Okay you say regrow but even so he had little time to give his memories that actually happened and not a 'cure'. That would take more energy I imagine since it didn't actually happen.

Comment: @Pryftan: If there were a cure, Snape probably would have used it in some other situation in the past, of which he had a memory.

Comment: @chirlu Honestly I don't buy that theory. He did cast it on James but why on earth would he cure it for James? Besides that it's rather irrelevant when the ear is actually gone isn't it? That itself would be reason enough to not include anything. Do you really think that Severus wouldn't know what happened to the ear? Do you really think he didn't know the ear was missing? Of course it was missing when it was severed off high up in the air.

Comment: @Pryftan "The fact Harry waved his wand is what made the wound more serious. Remember that it acts like an invisible sword slashing" I don't think so you know, it's what meant that Malfoy's injuries were spread over a larger area, but the power was far less concentrated, the cuts would have been shallower. To use your precise analogy would you rather someone slashed wildly at you with a sword, or chose a nice vulnerable part of you and plunged the sword in or else cut a controlled cut deliberately and precisely? If I had a choice between only those two fates I'll take door number 1 please

Comment: @Au101 That depends actually. The amount of damage that a blade can cause when targeted is bad yes but it can also cause a large amount of damage when wildly slashed or used recklessly. There was a time I was suicidal and although it wasn't actually one of my ways there was a time I badly hurt myself in a place I didn't even 'target' and I was quite lucky in many ways. Even so it only takes one thing to cause potentially fatal damage. Do we even know where Draco was slashed? Does Rowling even know the full significance there? If not then this isn't even possible to analyse properly.

Comment: @Au101 That being said: it's certainly true an experienced swordsman could easily kill someone. But that doesn't make my point any less valid. Nor does it in fact make your point less valid, I'd argue.

Comment: @Pryftan I'm sorry to hear what you went through, I wish you all the best.

Comment: Let me try and elaborate a bit: just because you're slashing wildly doesn't mean you can't hit a vital organ. You could. That's the point. Furthermore the body parts do work together and that shouldn't be discounted either. But whatever the case neither of us are wrong.

Comment: @Au101 Thank you very much. Means a great deal to me. But it's part of who I am and it shaped me and I have no regrets now. That doesn't mean I don't have my own set of demons but I’m a much better person and far better off than I was. And as much pain as I suffered and indeed suffer I wouldn't have it any other way. Perspective is a wonderful thing that took me a long time to appreciate but it's extremely helpful and as of last year I even can feel pride and happiness. But thank you very much. Means a great deal to me - more than you can know! :)

Comment: Well, we aren't dealing with swords. I'm sure you can do more damage than you mean to with a flailing blade, all I was saying in my answer was I would imagine that if the wand is constantly moving and not concentrated on a point, the cuts it makes, the marks it leaves, will be less deep, or at least we can easily imagine so, expect so. I had in my mind something more like fire. I wouldn't want someone to wave a blowtorch all over my body from a foot away, but I'd rather that than keep it in one place for a 10 seconds. But either way.

Comment: Indeed. But the analogy is still valid. And... that's all I am going to say because the site is whining about so-called chat (hardly - unless you consider your regards chatting). I know what you're saying and I would say we're both right but we're thinking of different things. Hopefully nobody that follows the sheep moves this over to chat but whatever the case I have much more important things to worry about lately and I only checked here as I knew I had some replies and I wanted to get it over with.

Comment: @Pryftan Feelin' the same way. I think you've got a lot to be proud of. Take care and all the best to you

Comment: @Au101 Thanks mate. Means a lot. And yes I do indeed have a lot to be proud of.  I know that well now although I still have doubts (that's a complicated story) even when the evidence is staring me right in the face. I am a winner of the longest running Internet contest too - the International Obfuscated C Code Contest and that takes an amazing amount of creativity, ingenuity and skill to win. I knew I could and if I do find another interesting thing to obfuscate I can do it again. But ...let's not continue. I apologise for making the site whine about chat. *shrug* Thanks for kind remarks!

Comment: "and if it was possible to heal Malfoy's wounds it was possible to heal George's."you mean Bill's?

Answer (score 1):

[From the sectumsempra wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sectumsempra)

> Though the aforementioned healing spell may heal the wounds and dittany may prevent scars, any body parts that have been severed by this curse cannot be grown back (a trait of dark magic's permanent effects), as demonstrated by George Weasley when he lost his left ear to the spell.

So no, Snape couldn't have healed George's ear

Comment: That website is effectively citing the same quote from the book

Comment: This is a circular answer.  It couldn't have been done because it wasn't done.

Comment: Can you provide any canon quotes to support this answer? (The wiki isn't a canon source.)

Comment: The Wikia is notoriously an unreliable source for quotes.

Comment: @GoodPerson While I admit that the Wikia isn't the most reliable place for quotes, and this is a theory on my part, but what if because the body part was actually severed (unlike draco, who had stab wounds, no severed parts,) that is why it was unable to be healed?

Answer (score 1):

Speculation: it could have, but only by Snape.

Snape uses the Vulnera Sanentur spell to heal Malfoy's wounds when Harry attacks him using the Sectumsempra spell, so I suppose the spell had that only antidote.

Some may argue that cursed wounds can't be healed, but it could be more like snake venom: any antivenom couldn't be used against any venom, but pairing the correct antivenom with the venom does work.
Can't know for sure, since Snape isn't there to actually cast the spell.