# Why did Alastor Moody only have a prosthetic leg?

Tags: harry-potter

The eyes are more delicate and complex than your legs, so why couldn't magic fix his legs if they were less delicate and complex than eyes and Moody had a magical eye?

Comment: Perhaps he spent all his money on the eye?  Perhaps he doesn't care so much about the leg because the prosthetic works?  Perhaps the injury was different, and magically inflicted?

Comment: He replaced his lost eye with an enchanted fake eyeball; he didn't fix his eye using magic that also made it magical.

Comment: Related; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207968/why-couldnt-moody-use-dittany-on-his-nose

Answer (score 5):

In general if an organ was lost in effect of Dark Magic it cannot be magically restored. It is explained by Molly Weasley in Deathly Hallows:

> Mrs. Weasley had staunched his bleeding now, and by the lamplight Harry saw a clean, gaping hole where George’s ear had been.
>
> “How is he?”
>
> Mrs. Weasley looked around and said, “I can’t make it grow back, not when it’s been removed by Dark Magic. But it could have been so much worse... He’s alive.”

Alastor Moody lost both his eye and his leg in duels with Death Eaters when he worked as an Auror. Most probably they were hit with strong spells and so can never be truly healed.

Please note that his eye wasn't really fixed. He placed a magical artifact in his orbit which substituted the eye. In a similar way his prosthetic leg substituted a real leg.

The question remains if he could have used a magical prosthetic leg instead of a simple wooden one. Plausibly yes, if such an item existed.

The only artificial limb mentioned in the books is the silver arm conjured by Lord Voldemort for Wormtail. But in the end the arm turned upon Wormtail and strangled him. I doubt Moody would like to use anything of that sort.

Answer (score 2):

Moody was retired after he got the injuries in the First Wizarding War. Being a retired Auror, and seeing Dark wizards everywhere, he would have wanted a magical eye that can see though things more than a leg. He probably prioritized an eye over a leg.

Comment: But why couldn't he have both?