# Infinite food source via self-cannibalism in Harry Potter

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory

In the Harry Potter universe, one limitation of magic is the ability to generate food from nothing, being one of the five exceptions to Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration. There are notably special cases noted at the [Harry Potter Wikia page](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gamp%27s_Law_of_Elemental_Transfiguration), mainly:

> It should be noted that while food cannot be outright created from nothing, it
>   can be multiplied if one already has some food to multiply, it can be enlarged
>   or the food can be summoned if one knows the approximate location and is fairly
>   sure the food will still be there. It should also be noted that while food
>   cannot be conjured, consumable liquids such as sauces and potable water can
>   be.

Also, it seems that if one has significant capabilities as a healer, all flesh wounds that aren't the result of a curse or jinx, can be repaired via incantations and no additional tonics, potions, ointments, etc.

Assuming we aren't concerned with diseases resulting from cannibalism, such as [kuru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuru_%28disease%29), is there anything, beyond a lack of pain tolerance, that would stop a wizard from just periodically lopping off his leg, healing it back; and cooking, cloning, and deliciously seasoning (due to free ability to summon a nice white wine sauce) one's own lower leg? Maybe transfigure some of it into a nice chianti and fava beans.

Or maybe, if a pair of wizards worked in coordination, ripped out the other's liver, kind of like [Prometheus's being eaten daily in Greek mythology](https://www.desy.de/gna/interpedia/greek_myth/creationMan.html)? Sounds like a viable way to have infinite food and water. [Kind of like the fish and bread story in Christian mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feeding_the_multitude) (feeding tons of people with a single fish and loaf of bread), but a bit more gory. Organ meat should provide enough vitamins and calories to cover most nutritional requirements.

Comment: Please let me know why downvoting. This is a serious question with prior research, sources, and references.

Comment: Technically, no, there's probably nothing to stop people from doing that. Wizards presumably share the general distaste and disgust for cannibalism, though, and there's no _reason_ to do this either. I doubt they'd be able to transfigure a leg into a Chianti or fava beans, though. There's no reference to anyone changing one type of food into another, at least.

Comment: Disturbing post, but I wouldn't downvote it because of that. Why not just multiply ordinary food and avoid all the pain, fuss and bother? If your suggestion is viable in-universe, I could only imagine it being used in emergency circumstances—or by very strange wizards.

Comment: @rosesunhill Let's assume it's like in the books where the trio is out of food and on the run. I always wondered why they couldn't just transfigure moss into cheese, and duplicate it.

Comment: Why not just do all that to a chicken?

Comment: @Oldcat I'm basing this off the scenario in the final book after Ron gets splinched, and they have no food to begin with. Always wondered why they just don't peel some edible pine bark, or some moss. Transfigure, clone repeat.

Comment: @Dogbert Cheese is a processed food, while moss is alive. Does anything in the canon address if food can be transformed from one state into the other? Also, I would have to check, but I doubt all species of moss are safe to eat.

Comment: @rosesunhill To be honest, I don't know if food can be transfigured. I do see an infinite source of steak roast, water, and HP sauce.

Comment: Have we seen examples of people actually gaining mass through healing, or have we only see things like healing broken bones? If people do gain mass (regrowing lost parts), do we know if this is a fast process, or is it possible it takes a while and requires them to eat at least as much food mass during the process as the mass of the part they're growing back?

Comment: @Hypnosifl That would be interesting if even magic don't trump the [law of conservation of mass](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/deptfiles/genchem/sstutorial/Text1/Tx14/tx14.html). I think it does though, since water is a freebie.

Comment: Frankly, creating water bothers me. One could flood the entire world that way. Or drown your enemies.

Comment: @Dogbert - Well, maybe the fact that there is a special limitation on creating food suggests the rules work differently for biological substances?

Comment: @Hypnosifl I don't know. The ability to summon sauces for free concerns me, as they're both organic and contain calories. Imagine being able to drown an opposing army with a flood of Frank's Red Hot sauce.

Comment: ... And then eat them!!!

Comment: I don't think you can get kuru from eating your own flesh.

Comment: @Paul True, but I also was thinking of the example where two buddies eat each others' livers periodically.

Comment: If all you need to know is the "approximate" location of the food to summon it..."Accio Hogwarts Hugglepuff Table's Bread!" (during meal time) Or "Accio McDonald's on 4th Ave Big Mac!"

Comment: Seems easier to just buy food. That way you don't have to chop your own legs off.

Comment: @Dogbert The Wiki is unreliable... the sauce part is referring to when Mrs. Weasley was making dinner. She probably had the sauce stored somewhere else and was just summoning it. That is the more accepted explanation anyway, considering making water has its own spell.

Comment: @Hypnosifl If you count Harry's bones growing back. Lockhart made them disappear and the Skele-grow potion grew them back. Not sure if that counts as there was a potion involved, and not just a spell. Same would go for any of the Polyjuice potions too...

Comment: @Dogbert Your reference to HP sauce is quite disturbing in the context of this question ... ;-)

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27872/can-any-body-part-be-regenerated-with-magic

Comment: @randal'thor [I'm surprised you didn't find the wine and edamame reference more disturbing :)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVlkZVAw8Gc). Thank you everyone for treating this bizarre question as a serious, though disturbing, enquiry.

Comment: @randal'thor [Perhaps some fava beans and a nice chianti is more to your liking? Or Amarone perhaps?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzC1Dn0gqgE)

Comment: The idea of living off one of the wizard's liver has a problem - hypervitaminosis A. There is a case of an Antarctic explorer (Xavier Metz) possibly dying from eating too much sled dog liver in 1913.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I had thought of that, but didn't mention it before. My guess is if they can take turns lopping off a leg below the knee (little chance of a miss and hitting a vital part with a simple large bladed axe), there's calories, and the occasional liver to *complement* that mostly due to its mineral and vitamin content. The liver part would be harder though, as it would either require a 30 minute procedure (inconvenient while on the run, even with a magic tent), or the use of a pile driver (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pile_driver).

Comment: What's unclear about this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wizards can't grow lost body parts with (normal) magic. Only dark wizards like Voldemort can do that like in the case of Scabbers during his comeback.

> “And now Wormtail was whimpering. He pulled a long, thin, shining silver dagger from inside his cloak. His voice broke into petrified sobs.
>
> “Flesh - of the servant - w-willingly given - you will - revive - your master.”
>
> He stretched his right hand out in front of him - the hand with the missing finger. He gripped the dagger very tightly in his left hand and swung it upward.”
>
> <sub>*-Harry Potter and The Goblet of Fire, Chapter-32*</sub>

Voldemort might have promised him to give back his hand after he returns,

> “My Lord…” he choked, “my Lord…you promised…you did promise…”
>
> “Hold out your arm,” said Voldemort lazily.
>
> “Oh Master…thank you, Master…”
>
> He extended the bleeding stump, but Voldemort laughed again.
>
> “The other arm, Wormtail.”
>
> “Master, please…please…”
>
> <sub>*-Harry Potter and The Goblet of Fire, Chapter-33*</sub>

Even though you have a new hand, it will not be under your control completely. Scabbers was killed by his own hand when he hesitated to attack Harry.

> “You’re going to kill me?” Harry choked, attempting to prise off the metal fingers. “After I saved your life? You owe me, Wormtail!”
>
> The silver fingers slackened. Harry had not expected it: He wrenched himself free, astonished, keeping his hand over Wormtail’s mouth. He saw the ratlike man’s small watery eyes widen with fear and surprise: He seemed just as shocked as Harry at what his hand had done, at the tiny, merciful impulse it had betrayed, and he continued to struggle more powerfully, as though to undo that moment of weakness.
>
> “And we’ll have that,” whispered Ron, tugging Wormtail’s wand from his other hand.
>
> Wandless, helpless, Pettigrew’s pupils dilated in terror. His eyes had slid from Harry’s face to something else. His own silver fingers were moving inexorably toward his own throat.
>
> <sub>*-Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows,Chapter-23*</sub>

Comment: After reviewing [a separate question related to this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27872/can-any-body-part-be-regenerated-with-magic), it seems this strategy won't work. Thanks!

Comment: I did not come across that answer,thanks. The first one to pass my mind when I read your question was Scabbers, but the answer there contains many more

Comment: Additionally, there's much less painful schemes wizards could do to get food.  For example, they could transfigure garbage into useful things, and trade that to muggles in exchange for food.

Comment: I think "wizards can't grow lost body parts" is too broad, even if it's true they can't grow back lopped off limbs without dark magic. I think [Skele-Gro](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Skele-Gro) counts as regrowing body parts--Lockhart accidentally caused the bones to disappear from Harry Potter's arm entirely, and Harry had to take this potion to grow them back.

Comment: In Wormtail's case it was a silver hand, so it hardly counts as being regrown, by dark magic or otherwise.

Comment: You'd expect, if it was easy enough for wizards to re-grow body parts, Moody might have gotten himself a new leg. Unless he just liked the style...

Answer (score 8):

Let's first establish one thing:

### Gamp's law is not necessarily violated

Unfortunately, canon is very unclear on what can or cannot be conjured, or indeed when something is being conjured, as opposed to transformed or enlarged. 
Hermione does state explicitly what the rules for "food" are:

> "It’s impossible to make good food out of nothing! You can Summon it
>   if you know where it is, you can transform it, you can increase the
>   quantity if you’ve already got some..."

It's unclear what exactly "food" is here. It must include at least anything that people in Britain normally eat, or it would hardly be a law. There are several conjuration spells that give rise to possible contradictions, but they in turn have possible justifications.

1. *Aguamenti* can produce water, presumably drinkable, since Harry tried to produce some for Dumbledore. Thus water may not be food for the purposes of Gamp's laws. However, you "can Summon food if you know where it is." Who is to say that *Aguamenti* does not simply Summon water from some stationary freshwater source. Or, if this is perhaps implausible, there is always a significant quantity of water present in the air, in the form of vapor. This of course is quite contrary to the situation with beefsteak. It is possible that this charm merely duplicates existing water molecules.
2. Molly Weasley appears to have produced sauce from her wand. However, it seems  most probable that she was either Summoning it or had simply stored it there. In fact, with its explicit reference to both food conjuration and Molly Weasley, this is probably precisely the situation Hermione's quote was meant to explain.
3. Spells like *Avis* can  produce birds, which are by default edible. However, it is entirely probable that these constructs differ fundamentally from real birds (otherwise magic could produce not just food, but life).

None of these situations, then, present fundamental challenges to Gamp's Laws. Potterwiki insists that sauce can be conjured, but it is notoriously inaccurate. The original text does not necessarily  support this interpretation.

Similarly, healing spells do not necessarily conjure anything.

1. Ron's splinched arm had to be regrown the long way.
2. When Severus Snape healed Draco Malfoy of injuries sustained from *Sectumsempra*, it is not at all clear that he was conjuring back Malfoy's blood. On the contrary, he seemed simply to be clotting his blood and joining his skin back together:

   > The flow of blood seemed
   >   to ease; Snape wiped the residue from Malfoy’s face and repeated
   >   his spell. Now the wounds seemed to be knitting.
3. Pettigrew's arm was not regenerated by Voldemort; Voldemort had to give him an entirely artifical replacement.

The one big problem, of course, is Skele-Gro. This potion seems to grow back all the bones in Harry's arm over the course of a night, without drawing on his own mineral reserves (which would in any case be insufficient. I see two possibilities. The first, of course, is that bones are insufficiently nutritious to wizards for Gamp's law to apply. This seems unlikely, since bones contain not only minerals, as might be found in any conjured inorganic object, but amino acids such as proline and glycine.

Far more likely, however, is that the a small amount of bone is formed from the components of the Skele-Gro itself, which is then magically increased in quantity. This would not violate Gamp's law, regardless of how much bone was produced.

**So conjuring flesh out of nothing would not work. But you might be able to increase the quantity of flesh you already had.**

### So why did the Trio not multiply chicken meat (or something)

- Just because bone can be multiplied, does not mean that flesh can, or that Hermione knows how. She may not even know how to replicate bone. Gamp's laws are not the only limitations to magic. Besides, do they really want to eat nothing but bone broth? Could they survive on that?
- Replication may not be infinite. It may well be that magically replicated  food can only be increased so much, and loses some fidelity with each increase. After replicating one chicken multiple times, you might end up with a Dementor or something.

Comment: The last sentence is awesome.

Comment: JKR has said that conjured things just don't last. So, presumably, if you cast Avis and then ate the birds, you would get nothing from it. Or, you might get something at first, then be left empty. Like eating certain fast foods really.

Comment: @A.Darwin Agreed. First time I've seen someone consider "data loss" with each reproduction.